# MySQL group by two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with the fields id, name, address.
Some entries have identical names but different addresses; some have identical addresses but different names.

I want to get a list including one entry at most for each unique address and one entry at most for each unique name.

If I could do a group by name then put the results in a temp table and then select again and do a group by address, then I would get exactly what i want - but that seems too complicated.

And doing a "group by name,address" will not give me what I am looking for - that would include entries for all different combinations of name,address whereas I want one entry for each name and one for each address. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you would need two queries, since the result set for each column would be a different length.  Why not do two selects, one for each column, grouping by that column?

Comment: What result do you expect from this set? (a,x),(a,y),(b,x),(b,y)

Comment: Im not 100% sure on what your end goal looks like, but it sounds like the DISTINCT keyword my be of use to you.  Again without knowing your desired result I can't get any more specific.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a nicer way to do this, and I'm making some assumptions about what you want, but you could try something like this:

```
SELECT Name, '' AS Address, Count(Address) AS RowCount
  FROM TableName
  GROUP BY Name
UNION
SELECT '' AS Name, Address, Count(Name) AS RowCount
  FROM TableName
  GROUP BY Address
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not give me a name, address pair but a list of names followed by a list of addresses. As to my question, if it wasn't clear - if I could go a group by name then put the results in a temp table and then select again and do a group by address, then I would get exactly what i want - but that seems too complicated.

Comment: olym,you need to answer piotrm comment